# Why is the snapping tool leaving some gaps between the shapes snapped together? (Affinity Designer)

Tags: vector, affinity-designer

[image]

I am using Snapping tool with the default settings. [image]

However, as you can see, it is leaving gaps between shapes, thus totally undoing the whole point of the tool, if I have to manually line them up anyway. How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks to me like the adjacent shapes don’t line up. It’s snapping the ‘inner’ points to each other, leaving a gap between the ‘outer’ points because the angle and distance between the inner and outer points are different in the two shapes. Are you suggesting it should actually _change_ the shape of the element when snapping? Because that would be a lot more difficult and bug-prone to introduce, and it would probably also be very annoying most of the time.

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood how the tool works, shouldn't it line up the one I am positioning with the underlying point? There's no need to change the position of the previous point I'm using as the snap.

Comment: Which point were you snapping by? It can only snap by one point at a time (unless multiple points line up exactly). It looks to me as if the objects were snapped on the inner point at the bottom, which means there’s no gap between those two points. Any other points will only have no gap if they line up. That’s how snapping works. If they don’t line up, you’ll have to adjust the shape by snapping individual _points_, rather than snapping the entire shape.

Answer (score 4):

I've a totally different response here: your snap settings are basically *Layout* snap-settings - for organising *a whole composition, spread or document*; they are unequivocally **NOT** ***drawing*** snap settings at all!

Note that you *are* snapping to object bounding boxes, but **not** to gaps or sizes, *and most crucially* you ***don't*** have snap to Shape Key Points **or** Object Geometry enabled - this means your snapping candidates were the spread, the various object *bounding boxes* and ***no actual geometry or node snaps at all.***

I'm *quite impressed* you came as close as you did with your snapping set like this.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I think this will help! I'll go back and try again and return with my results.

Answer (score 3):

This is said already in the comments, but here's some images:

[image]

In the left the red shape refuses to sit perfectly when I move it with the normal selection tool, no matter do I have snapping ON or OFF, only one corner can be in the right place at a time.

In the middle I succeeded to place with the node tool  three of the four corners of the red shape when I put snap=ON. The 4th corner was a problem because there's nothing to snap.

In the right  a horizontal and a vertical help line were drawn. The problematic corner snapped easily to the crossing with the node tool

**Not asked:** Exact seam isn't always good, because it's partially transparent due anti-aliasing. You can see the background as faint stripes through them. Overlapping prevents it.